Right rear door won't open because my mechanic reversed the two cables that go into the door latch
I have a 2011 Hyundai Santa Fe. My right rear door no longer opens from the inside or outside because my mechanic reversed the two cables into the door latch (one cable for the lock, one for the handle to open the door). The door latch can't be removed without removing the door panel, but unfortunately the screws to remove the door panel can only be accessed with the door open. Is there a fix for this situation? He and I both don't know how to proceed at this point...

Your mechanic can look for a replacement door panel through the usual channels for used parts. If found and reasonably priced, they can hack a ragged hole in your door panel and unlock the door.
If a replacement is not available or too costly, they can drill two small holes in the appropriate area of the door panel, one for a flexible borescope and one for a wire loop to grab the unlatching mechanism. The holes can be repaired with trim plugs.
